# Prove that $f(x) = e^{- \lfloor x \rfloor}dx$ is integrable over any interval [a,b].

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that $f(x) = e^{- \lfloor x \rfloor}dx$ is integrable over any interval [a,b].

I have a hunch that it is a monotonic function since f(x) is composed of decreasing step functions, so it is bounded above by $f(x) = e$ where $x \in [-1,0)$ and below by 0.

Let $m_k=\inf_{x_{k-1} \leq x\leq x_k} f(x)$, and $M_k=\sup_{x_{k-1} \leq x\leq x_k} f(x)$

Also would it suffice to say $\inf U(f,P) = \sup L(f,P)$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n M_k(x_k-x_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^n m_k(x_k-x_{k-1}) \\
\end{align}
$$

since $\sup f(x) = \inf f(x),\ \forall x \in [\lfloor x \rfloor, \lceil x \rceil)$.

Comment: Its discontinuity set is countable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow how that implies integrability.

Comment: Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability. A bounded function on a compact interval is Riemann integrable iff it is continuous almost everywhere (i.e. the set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero).

Comment: A monotone function is easily seen to be integrable from the definition: Use the partition $P_{n}$ with $n$ equal-length subintervals, and show$$U(f, P_{n}) - L(f, P_{n}) = |f(b) - f(a)|\, \frac{b-a}{n},$$which can be made arbitrarily small.